# Reading JSON file using R

Tags: r, fromjson

```
product_id.datahandler({"ID": [], "ProductName": ["Marbel Mabel"], "Description": ["pearl white, natural marbel"] .....})
```

I have a data as above. I tried to read it as JSON using `fromJSON` but failed (`not all data was parsed (0 chars were parsed out of a total of 39890 chars)`). How could i clean `product_id.datahandler(` and `)` first before using `fromJSON` to read as JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use some `regex` to clean the string? Here using `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

jsontext <- 'product_id.datahandler({"ID": [], "ProductName": ["Marbel Mabel"], "Description": ["pearl white, natural marbel"]})'

jsontext |>
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

#Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#product_id.datahandler({"ID": [
#  (right here) ------^

jsontext |>
  str_replace_all(".*\\..*\\(\\{", "\\{") |> # Matching: "character.character({"
  str_replace_all("\\}\\)", "\\}") |> 
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

#$ID
#list()
#
#$ProductName
#[1] "Marbel Mabel"
#
#$Description
#[1] "pearl white, natural marbel"
```